# HOW can i make an html page with bat file?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make an HTML file with batch file.
But it didn't work. How can I make that?

my bat  commands

```
set/p n=1:
copy con c:\55.HTML
my HTML page %n%
```

but this commands just makes a `55.HTML` and when you open that it is empty :/

Comment: It doesn't work because (besides that you have to be administrator if creating a file on c:\\),   http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2530CJTj   set /p n=1:   will change the prompt and take some input which will be stored in n,  but the input you enter at that `1:`  won't be executed.  So you could type DIR there you will see no output. it will just be stored in 'n'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you expected

```
copy con c:\55.HTML
```

to read the next line(s) as if it were a shell here-document.  Since the result is empty, more likely it did not do that, but copied nothing (in a quick check, the script hangs on the `copy` command, and killing that moves on to an unrecognized command "my").

You can always do this however:

```
echo my HTML page %n% >>c:\55.html
```